# YouTube video first starts with clarity but blurs even after completely buffered

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

In this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/706091/dual-monitor-screen-gets-blurry-when-i-watch-a-youtube-video-in-full-screen-mo)
he has problem only when video is watched fullscreen but in my case video starts with good clarity even in 144p and blurs just after a couple of seconds. Sometimes it occurs at different time and again appears with clarity. I don't know whats the reason for it. I want to watch video in this resolution only because I have slow broadband connection and video with this resolution will buffur quickly... I'm using google chrome web browser, windows 8 enterprise edition and 512kbps broad band connection(I get approx 26 to 30kbps for download).

I don't know what makes it blur after its been buffered completely and even when I play from beginning it behaves as before as if the video itself is blurred while uploading. Please help me.

Comment: there's obviously a glitch with chrome, send them a report about it.

Comment: No @Sickest, the suggested (question with answer) clearly states that only application interface is blurry, but i'm not having any blurry interface but the video is blurry. if you want to see the difference i can upload both images.

Comment: i've seen this problem all over the internet, its only with chrome. I can't reproduce the problem, you have to take it up with google, hence the make a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google started streaming many of it's YouTube videos using the new [MPEG-DASH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-DASH) protocol since late 2013. MPEG-DASH is currently only supported on Chrome. It is known to have caused some [bugs](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/cK0STo19oU4). MPEG-DASH can switch video quality while playing to adapt to bandwidth availability.

Comment: Firefox does support DASH now.

Comment: It did from version 21 to 23 but was disabled by default. They replaced DASH with [Media Source Extensions](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Platform/MediaSourceExtensions) so that somewhere mid-2014, dash.js could become compatible with Firefox.

Comment: So wats the solution now @Duvrai? Is there anyway to fix it in low resolution?

Comment: @Heptite anyway to fix this issue at lower resolution?